# Android app is misconfigured for facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse

I'm trying to integrate FB login for my android app and **have already followed the steps in the previous questions so don't downvote please or try and duplicate**,when the window pops up I get an error in dialogue saying the app is misconfigured

i'm generating my key in the following way

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS6\JVM\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias
androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Marc\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Users\Ma
rc\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\users\marc\openssl\bin\openssl" base6
4
Enter keystore password:  android
THIS SHOWS A KEY
```

In my facebook app config panel the options are set to the following:

Package Name: app.android.amazingjobs

Class Name: app.android.amazingjobs.activity_mainmenu **Should this be the .java class or the XML activity name?**

Key Hash: MY KEY

Code is as follows:

```
package app.android.amazingjobs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Mainmenu extends Activity {
    private static final String FACEBOOK_APPID = "123456789";
    private static final String FACEBOOK_PERMISSION = "email, publish_stream";
    private final Handler mFacebookHandler = new Handler();
    private TextView loginStatus;
    private FacebookConnector facebookConnector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
        Button Searchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.JobSearchButton);
        Searchbutton.setOnClickListener(StartSearch);
        this.facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector(FACEBOOK_APPID, this, getApplicationContext(), new String[] {FACEBOOK_PERMISSION});

        if (facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
        } else {
          facebookConnector.login();
        }

    }

    private OnClickListener StartSearch = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Mainmenu.this, SearchForJobs.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

EDIT

My logcat in eclipse show the following messages while loading the facebook login:

```
10-28 19:37:27.596: D/ATRecorder(12643): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@405279f0
10-28 19:37:27.616: D/WindowManagerImpl(12643): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40522bf0
10-28 19:37:31.220: D/ATRecorder(12643): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@4053b308
10-28 19:37:31.340: D/Facebook-Util(12643): GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/414522241948993?format=json&fields=supports_attribution
10-28 19:37:32.381: D/WindowManagerImpl(12643): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40522bf0
10-28 19:37:33.082: D/dalvikvm(12643): GC_CONCURRENT freed 250K, 47% free 3036K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 6ms+3ms
10-28 19:37:34.483: D/NativeCrypto(12643): returned from sslSelect() with result 1, error code 2
10-28 19:37:34.673: D/Facebook-publish(12643): Unsupported get request.
10-28 19:38:50.817: D/WindowManagerImpl(12643): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052d1d8
10-28 19:38:54.221: W/KeyCharacterMap(12643): Can't open keycharmap file
10-28 19:38:54.221: W/KeyCharacterMap(12643): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/atmel-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='atmel-touchscreen'
10-28 19:38:54.221: I/KeyCharacterMap(12643): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-28 19:38:54.571: D/WindowManagerImpl(12643): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052d1d8
```

UPDATE:

Right it seems Jesse is right, it is a case of having the wrong key, even though the keytool was asking me for a password I was still using the wrong one, not sure why I wasnt getting the logcat messages though, i've implemented the code from here:

http://p-xr.com/implementing-facebook-into-your-app-invalid-key-with-keytool/

This outputs the correct key in logcat to use in your app configuration.

Thanks to jesse for his help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Class Name: app.android.amazingjobs.activity_mainmenu Should this be the .java class or the XML activity name?

It's the .java class, so something like "app.android.amazingjobs.MainActivity".

Also, other people seem to have trouble getting the correct hash key using the terminal command.  I suggest trying this more friendlier way of getting the correct hash key.

See the answer here: [Android: Facebook Login doesn't work](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13049346/android-facebook-login-doesnt-work/13059177#13059177)

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to find an error like that in logcat.. I have the long list but if I for instance type "does not match" in the filter I don't get anything?

Comment: Even if I apply the Errors filter from the dropdown it doesn't show anything at all from within the session filter

Comment: Are you using the Android 3.0 SDK beta or the current version of the SDK?

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for your helping by the way, i'm using the GitHub release at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk - I was adapting the tutorial from http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/

Comment: Essentially i've just added all the class files from that tutorial to my project and then used the code above in the activity  after my splashscreen. Oh and i'm not using the AVD, i have my HTC desire S plugged in via USB and running it on the actual handset with the latest FB app installed also.

Comment: There should be a logcat error message about the key mismatch if you set `ENABLE_LOGGING` to true in `Util.java`.  I'm not sure why your logcat would not show it if you did all that.

Comment: Yeah its odd, I'm 99% sure I have the right key as I get asked for a password when I try the command line. I've added my logcat from eclipse above.